# How to find the count of users who follow the same order sequence?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble thinking this through. I have about 3 million rows with columns: userID, Channel the user last came in from before purchase, and their order sequence. I would like to find a way to the count of users that follow the same order sequences based on the channel. Is there a certain function that can help me accomplish this?

Ex. TPA --> TPA --> Email

- how many people follow this sequence?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the sequences using `string_agg()`:

```
select path, count(*) as num_users
from (select user_id,
             string_agg(channel, '-->') within group (order by sequence) as path
      from t
      group b user_id
     ) u
group by path
order by num_users desc;
```

`string_agg()` is a relatively new function.  In older versions of SQL Server, you would probably use XML functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count them, you could first group them, and then perform a count. In fact, once grouped you can do whatever you like...

```
WITH dte as (
  SELECT distinct
    userid,
    (
        SELECT Channel+'>'
        FROM MyTable t2
        WHERE t2.userid= t.userid
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) Concatenated
  FROM MyTable t
)
SELECT whatever
FROM dte
```

Hope this works out for you. :)